# Germany: How to fix typo in rental contract (need correction for dependent-visa)

Tags: visa, germany, rental, dependent-visa, contracts

In October 2020, I signed a rental contract in Berlin, Germany.
Unfortunately, I, with the landlord, missed an address typo in the rental agreement. The address should have been building number '5'. Instead, in the contract, it is building number '5A'.

Luckily, while doing the Anmeldung (filling the forms, etc.) I provided the correct address-i.e., building number '5'. So there is no issue with any other legal documents such as insurance, tax, etc.

Today I realized this mistake while going through the contract.

However, now I am in the middle of a dependent visa (family reunion visa) for my spouse. And just realized that I have submitted this contract with the incorrect address for the visa application.

Now I am worried if the visa authority will raise any issue regarding this address mismatch (Anmeldung vs. rental contact). And if they do, then will I have to submit a "fixed" copy of my rental contract.

So I wanted to ask,
Is there any legal way in Germany to fix a typo in the rental contract?
Something like "affidavit of correction" along with a copy of the rental agreement I can send to the German consulate beforehand and mention the mistake in advance?

Comment: Ask the landlord to write a letter that states that in the contract of [date] that the address was incorrectly written and it should understood as '5' instead of '5A'.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I can try this.